# Why won't the password length change when I put the desired length in the textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, password-generator

When I submit the desired password length, the length doesn't change.

There are two buttons:
the top one (which is smaller), is for submitting the password's length.
The bottom one (bigger), generates the password, taking the length that was inputted.

The default length is 12 characters, though I will make the minimum length 8, and the maximum 16.

```
def copy():
    copy_pw = Tk()
    copy_pw.withdraw()
    copy_pw.clipboard_clear()
    copy_pw.clipboard_append(password)
    copy_pw.update()

def password_generator():
    lower_case = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    upper_case = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    numbers = "0123456789"
    symbol = "%^#*:;._-@`~"

    answer = lower_case + upper_case + numbers + symbol

    global password_length
    password_length = 12

    global password
    password = "".join(random.sample(answer, password_length))
    print("Password has been generated: ", password)
    text.config(text = password)

def submit_length():
    user_length = entry.get()
    password_length = user_length

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Generator")

length = Button(window, text = 'Enter')
length.pack()
length.config(command = submit_length)
length.config(font =('Segoe UI', 10))
length.config(bg = '#009DFF')
length.config(fg = '#ffffff')
length.config(activebackground = '#009DFF')
length.config(activeforeground = '#ffffff')

entry = Entry()
entry.pack()
entry.config(font = ('Segoe UI', 12))

button = Button(window, text = 'Generate password')
button.pack()
button.config(command = password_generator)
button.config(font =('Segoe UI', 22))
button.config(bg = '#009DFF')
button.config(fg = '#ffffff')
button.config(activebackground = '#009DFF')
button.config(activeforeground = '#ffffff')

text = Label(window, text = password)
text.pack()
text.config(font = ('Monospace', 25))
button.pack()

# copy password
copy_password = Menu(text, tearoff= 0, bg = "white", fg = "black")
copy_password.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy)

# popup on right click
text.bind("<Button - 3>", popup)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need `global password_length` in `submit_length`. You also have to convert it to an integer.

Comment: `password_generator` is replacing the value of `password_length` with `12`.

Comment: As I said above: **You also have to convert it to an integer**

Comment: Didn't work well, got this error:
password = "".join(random.sample(answer, password_length))
NameError: name 'password_length' is not defined
Happened after converting to int.

Comment: Declared password_length oustside of function.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `length` button and `submit_length()` function, you can just get the input length inside `password_generator()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable global in the function that assigns it, and convert to integer.

```
def submit_length():
    global password_length
    user_length = entry.get()
    password_length = int(user_length)
```